# Spring Security 3.2 Login Form Error - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Security 3.2 login form as what is mentioned on http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html (I have to make a few of changes on the login form I had for the previous SS). I can't log in due to the following error.

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

After I change the configuration to use the default login form, it works fine.

I run out of idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: more code is needed, which url are you posting to?

Comment: The action URL of the login form is stated in the document as "login".

Comment: SS 3.2 changes the way of login form configuration. The action URL in the login form must be the same as the URL of loginPage. This problem is resolved with the change.